# C# using fields in external class (to make stopwatch)

Tags: c#

I'm pretty stumped on this problem. I'm trying to create a "stopwatch" assignment, however the fields (DateTime startTime, DateTime stopTime) and a Read-only field (ElapsedTime) need to be on the business layer class (Timing.cs.BL) The business layer also needs to have methods StartClock() and StopClock().

If have my UI form setup ... lblDisplay (for the elapsed time), lstSplits (for the split times), btnStart, btnStop, btnReset, btnSplit.

I've looked at TimeSpan, DateTime and elapsed.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

my problem is i dont know how to build a method ElapsedTime in the business layer (Timing.cs.BL) and then kick the elapsedTime to the lblDisplay on the form UI. I can pass the startClock and stopClock to the form, but I dont know how to generate the elapsedTime (in the BL) and then pass it to the form so it updates there.

Using Visual Studio 2015 to build it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should just copy/paste your entire homework assignment, it's likely more understandable than this gem of incoherence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose and consume.

In the business layer, you need to *expose* the value you want, e.g.

```
class MyBusinessLayerClass
{
    private StopWatch _stopWatch;
    public TimeSpan ElapsedTime
    {
        get { return _stopWatch.Elapsed; }
    }
}
```

and then *consume* the value in the UI layer, somehow.  Perhaps you wish to update the elapsed time every second, so add a timer to your form and capture the [Tick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

```
private void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
     myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
}

private static void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
    MyBusinessObject o = GetMyBusinessObject();
    TimeSpan ts = o.ElapsedTime;
    string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
    this.lblTimeElapsed.Text = elapsedTime;
}
```